# Dependent Binary Data (or lack thereof) Affect on Jacobian Elements (and MLE's) in Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic

I am using logistic regression to produce the logit, etc.  I am using daily stock market price data as a basis for the binary dependent variable.  The 10-day future price difference is recorded in percentage terms and associated with the current date.  So today the dependent variable value would be equal to the price ten days from now(currently unknown) minus the price of today all divided by the price of today. This equation is then converted to a binary based on a condition of say <0%. <0% = 1  and  >=0%=0

Because the value of the close ten days from now is unknown I have unrecorded/unknown dependent variable values for the 9 values prior to the current date.

The Jacobian Matrix is used in discovering the maximum likelihood estimate Beta value. Because the Jacobian Matrix elements are constructed using the first derivative of likelihood function and the first derivative likelihood function uses the dependent binary value as an input, how do the blank values nearest to the current date contribute to the overall quality of the discovered Maximum Likelihood Betas, Error, etc?

I realize 9 absent days are generally going to have a lesser impact on the MLE when there are 1000 data points as compared to 50.  The issues seems like one to investigate rather than overlook.  How is best to handle this scenario?  Is there a standard approach to evaluating the impact of blank dependent values on MLE's, Errors, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a size-$T$ sample of prices $P_t,\;t=1,...,T$, and you form the sample

$$d_t \equiv \frac {P_{t+10}-{P_t}}{P_t}$$

The effect will be that your sample size is reduced. The first-first usable observation will now be

$$d_1 = \frac {P_{11}-{P_1}}{P_1}$$

and the last one will be

$$d_{T-10} = \frac {P_{T}-{P_{T-10}}}{P_{T-10}}$$

So you will be working with sample size $T^* = T-10$. One can asses the impact of this sample-size reduction, if the estimator's explicit formula is available (in which case it will include the sample size in some way).

This is the case for example when the estimators are Method of Moments estimators (i.e. sample means), (and sometimes MLEs coincide with MM estimators) or when one can obtain the finite-sample distribution of the estimator, that will include the sample size. Then one can calculate the moments like the variance and see how they are affected by changes in the sample size.

To consider the trivial example, let an i.i.d sample and we want to estimate the mean of the distribution. Then it is easy to find that the variance ratio of the sample mean from the smaller sample to the one from the larger sample is

$$\frac {\text{Var}(\bar X)|_{T^*}}{\text{Var}(\bar X)|_{T}} = \frac T{T-10}$$

If $T=50$ then the variance will be $25$% larger, when we lose 10 observations.

Etc

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  It is ultimately the variability in the convergence value of the MLE that I am interested in.  If I am understanding correctly, i may not be, the ratio between measures of variance on a simple mean using the differences in sample size gives insight into the quality of the MLE's.  Is the relationship between the ratio of variances proportional to the ratio of differences in the convergence values of the MLE's?

Comment: it occurred to me that the question may be sort of unnecessary altogether as a result of the use of beta tests to determine estimate quality.  So for instance if the set of MLE's is producing case "1" estimates at a 74% accuracy then we know where we are at in terms of the quality of the betas.